# Explaining arrays and ++ operator on index and value

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.2, post-increment

I was studying operators priority in php7.2 when I executed this code :

```
$i = 1;
$a[$i] = $i++;

var_dump($a);

$j = 1;
$b[$j++] = $j++;

var_dump($b);
```

And I get this result :

```
array(1) {
  [2]=>
  int(1)
}
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
```

I don't understand why this code give these outputs. I could get the first var_dump but the second seems really weird to me.

Could you explain how this two examples are interpreted by php step by step ?

I don't get the same results on php 4 though.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between pre-increment and post-increment? If not, go read up on that first of all.

Comment: __Never__ write such codes.

Comment: how shall this be specific to PHP 7.x ?? not even on PHP 4.x this would have made sense.

Comment: I am aware of the differences between pre-increment and post-increment. What I don't get is the order in which the array assignement is done and why the key and value are reversed in those two examples.

Comment: @MartinZeitler In php 4, the first var_dump gives you 1=>1

Comment: @MossetJérémie it is still utter non-sense, trying to increment an index value while accessing an index... the order of operations should be exactly the same, at least theoretically (and I'm not going to install PHP 4.x only to reproduce illogical code).

Comment: I hope this is not part of your study/book.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I wouldn't write such code. I'm just trying to know how php does interpret this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if C++ is a compile time language, there is no standard behaviour on instructios like `x = x++` and the result differs between compilers.

PHP is runtime precompiled and thus optimized on performance with regard of compilation time *and* execution time as well. The **behaviour is undefined** and may differ from version to version.

You should never rely on thus constructs within one instruction - in no language, except it was well defined in its specs.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of replying like other people who don't even know what they are talking about without testing/searching, here is a start for debugging the way that PHP is analysed when converted to byteCode.

https://derickrethans.nl/projects.html#vld

I've not enough time to do it myself.

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it is all about operator precedence.

The operators are being processed in this order :

1. [
2. ++ (from left to right)
3. =

The following code is being interpreted in these steps:

```
$i = 1;
$a[$i] = $i++;
```

1. $i++ returns 1 and is then incremented
2. $a[$i] is being allocated with $i === 2
3. $a[2] is being assigned with the return value of step 1. so $a[2] === 1

And with this code :

```
$j = 1;
$b[$j++] = $j++;
```

1. The left $j++ returns 1 and $j is being incremented
2. The right $j++ returns 2 (because it has been incremented in step 1) and $j is being incremented again. At this point, $j === 3
3. $b[1] is allocated because the first step returns 1.
4. $b[1] is being assigned with the return value of step 2. So $b[1] === 2

So the last example does almost the same thing as this :

```
function incrementInteger(int &$i): int
{
    ++$i;
    return $i - 1;
}

$j = 1;
$b[incrementInteger($j)] = incrementInteger($j);
```